# How to make expandable sliding menu?

Tags: ios, slidingmenu

Good day=) How to make a expandable sliding menu looks like 
http://yadi.sk/d/xsLWlWSrA7qj2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a million and one options for a slide out menu.

You need to do some searching for the one with the specific requirements you have:
https://github.com/andreamazz/SlideOutNavigation

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController

Tutorials
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
http://nickharris.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/ios-slide-out-navigation-code/
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-create-a-sliding-menu-for-ios/